# How do I write items from the Items file to csv and then append the csv file every time I run the program afterwards

Tags: scrapy

I want to create a csv file, fill it with items from the Items file and append the csv file with new data every time I run the program afterwards. My aim is to use cron to run it at certain intervals once it has been setup.

```
import scrapy
import json
from ..items import AnotherddItem
import datetime
import csv

class AnotherddSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ddgrab'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/all?source=private']

    csv_columns=['timestamp','sellerId','sellerName','adUrl']
    dict_data = [timestamp, sellerId, sellerName, adUrl]
    csv_file = 'test.csv'
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict_data:
            writer.writerow(data)
```

dict_data contains all the fields in my items.py file. I know what I have done here is wrong because the dict_data fields haven't been defined yet but I don't know how to access them.

Comment: Maybe this is worth opening a feature request upstream.

Comment: Thanks Gallaecio, I connected everything to a sqlite database and everything works well now. I have another problem though as in I'm unsure as to what to do next. More precisely how to go about it. I want to scrape the same urls but I want to scrape them an hour later, 24 hours later, 48 hours later etc. I can use the timestamp to do all of this but I'm wondering can I feed it through the same pipelines and into the same database with new columns representing the new data. I have it running on a crontab at the moment that runs every minute and I'd like to be able to scrape them again.

Comment: Sorry but this is my first project using python, scrapy so I'm on a steep learning curve and lots of things I'm unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to *append* data to your file you need to create a custom [pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) that will check if output file already exists and write **header** line if needed.